# 12.04 usb install "boot error"

Tags: installation, 12.04, boot, boot-failure

I downloaded 12.04 64bit, I checked with md5. Seems okay.
made bootable usb with usb creater.

Now if try to boot up from live usb. I just get "boot error". Nothing else.

nothing else. googled around. nothing comes out.

UPDATE:  some additional info.

- The usb manufacture is sony.
- it is fat32 partitioned.
- Most importantly I could install 12.04 on other systems by same usb.
- Yes, I definitely setup my Bios boot order to look for USB disk first.

Comment: some USBs dont want to be a bootable.Sandisk usb is an example.If u r on ubuntu try to make a multisystem by this way.http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/ This will help u save time for booting and shutdown of bootable usb and u can add and remove as many ISOs as possible.

Comment: @beeju  Thanks for the comment. I am not sure i understand how it helps me to put more isos in the same usb. updated my question could you go throught that once again. Thanks

Comment: Did u ever able to boot USB from this particular system? Next time when u give answer, include ur system configuration too.

Comment: MAke sure your BIOS is trying to boot from that particular device.

Comment: About multisystem...it allows to boot many ISOs with a greb menu on the USB.It never act as startup disk for installing any apps but can do all other activities as a live media.When u need to remove and add other ISOs just run the app and slect the one u want to remove and follow the instruction.A drag and drop of ISOs is also allowed.

Comment: @ErenTantekin Thanks for the Comment. USB is given first priority.,  if I take usb off its booting from the hard disk properly.. so I am fairly sure it is booting from the usb.

Comment: You have provided a lot of detail in your question about the bootable USB you created. But I did not see **anything** about the computer which the USB does **not** work on. If your USB works fine on other computer's but will not work on one, then it would certainly help to know at least the model and manufacturer of the computer with which you are having a problem. The more information you can supply about it the better, of course.

Comment: I get the same issue on my sons E-machines PC, it just wont boot from usb even though it's an option in the bios. The same usb can be booted from on my PC however, so I am certain this is a hardware related issue. The only way I can do it on my sons PC is with a live cd.

Comment: @ChrisCarter, I figured out the same. It was mainly because of buggy BOIS (for me., intel firmware). At the end I used a CD instead, didn't dare to update firmware..

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this has to do with the usb start up disk but with the BIOS.

Check out:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042487
for a user with a similar problem he fixed it by:

> go to Bios Boot Menu...
>   Search for ' USB Mass Storage Emulation type'
>   Default:`<Auto>`
>   Change it to:`<All Fixed Disc>`
>   or something similar

Comment: +1, the steps in post #6 of the above link solved my identical problem -- may only work with an Intel motherboard though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ext4` instead of `fat32`. If it still doesn't work, try `unetbootin` to get a Live-USB.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar error. And I think the reason lays in the way Sony formats the usb, or in my case the `sd-card`. 
I never had any problems with the card getting read by Ubuntu, but after a format inside the  `Sony`photocamera, i could not read it.

The program `Disk Utility` showed the card, formated as `fat32`, and after formatting it to `fat`, I could read it with no problems.

I would suggest, dont use a windows file system when installing a linux file system.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The problem is not in Ubuntu or Live USB creator softwares...the problem is in ur bios settings...

go to Bios Boot Menu...
Search for ' USB Mass Storage Emulation type'
Default:
Change it to:
or something similar

This was the Bios of Intel DP35DP MainBoard with P35 Chipset...
Right Now i am working from a USB Ubuntu !!!...